# Assembly IA-32 functions not behaving as they should

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, x86

Compiler: Nasm version 2.14.02

Linker: GNU LD (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34

OS: 64-bit Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Compilation/Linkage commands: nasm -f elf -o hello.o hello.asm | ld -m elf_i386 -o hello hello.o

Apologies for the vague title but I have no idea how to describe this succinctly. I have 2 functions which are supposed to, respectively, read an integer of up to 3 digits(not counting a '-' in case of negatives), and write any 32 bit integer pushed onto the stack before call.

```
section .data
endln db 0dh,0ah

ENDLNSIZE EQU $-endln

section .bss
entradaInteiro resd 1
contador resd 1
buffer resb 5

section .text
global _start

LerInteiro:
    enter 4,0               
                        
    mov eax, 3              
    mov ebx, 0              
    mov ecx, buffer
    mov edx, 5
    int 80h                 
    
    mov dword [contador], eax
    dec dword [contador]
    push eax
                        
    mov ebx, buffer         
                        
    cmp byte [buffer],'-'           
    jne _posInteiro
    
    dec dword [contador]
    mov dword [ebp-4], -1
    add ebx, 1
    jmp _continueInteiro
    
_posInteiro:
    mov dword [ebp-4], 1
    
_continueInteiro:
    mov eax, 0
    mov al, [ebx]
    sub eax, 30h
    
    mov ecx, [ebp + 8]              
                            
    mov dword [entradaInteiro], eax
    
    dec dword [contador]
_loopInteiro:
    cmp dword [contador], 0
    je _fimInteiro
    add ebx,1
    mov eax, 0
    mov al, [ebx]
    sub eax, 30h
    push eax
    mov eax,10
    mul dword [entradaInteiro]
    mov dword [entradaInteiro],eax
    pop eax
    add dword [entradaInteiro],eax
    dec dword [contador]
    
    
    jmp _loopInteiro
    
_fimInteiro:
    mov eax,[ebp - 4]
    mul dword [entradaInteiro]
    mov dword [entradaInteiro], eax
    
    
    
    pop eax
    leave                   
    ret

;----------------------------------------------------------------------

EscreverInteiro:                
                        
                        
                        
    enter 8,0
    
    mov dword [ebp-4],10
    ;mov ecx, [ebp + 8]
    ;mov dword [ebp - 8], ecx
    mov dword [contador], 0
    cmp dword [ebp + 8], 0
    jge _EscreveInteiroContinue     
    neg dword [ebp + 8]
    inc dword [contador]
    mov byte [buffer], '-'
    
_EscreveInteiroContinue:
    cdq
    mov ebx, buffer
    
        
_EscreveInteiroLoop:                
                        
    mov eax,[ebp + 8]
    cdq
    idiv dword [ebp - 4]
    mov dword [ebp + 8], eax
    add edx, 48
    mov byte [ebx], dl
    cmp dword [ebp + 8],0
    jz _EscreveInteiroLoopContinue
    mov cl, [ebx]
    mov byte [ebx+ 1 * 1], cl
_EscreveInteiroLoopContinue:
    inc dword [contador]
    add ebx,1
    cmp dword [ebp + 8],0
    jnz _EscreveInteiroLoop
    
                    
                    
    push dword [contador]
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1 
    mov ecx, buffer
    add ecx, [contador]
    mov edx, 1
    
_EscreveInteiroLoop2:
    int 80h
    dec dword [contador]
    jl _FimEscrever
    mov eax, 4
    dec ecx
    jmp _EscreveInteiroLoop2
    
_FimEscrever:
    pop dword [contador]
    
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, endln
    mov edx, ENDLNSIZE
    int 80h
    
    mov eax, [contador]
    leave
    ret 4

_start:
    call LerInteiro
    mov ebx, [entradaInteiro]
    push ebx
    call EscreverInteiro

    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h
```

Here's the problem: I want to be able to call LerInteiro, push whatever was stored in entradaInteiro, and then call EscreverInteiro to write it. This works for positive integers but not negative, as instead it writes the number preceded by its last digit(for example, '-45' outputs '545', '-12' outputs '212').
What's really frustrating is I've tested both functions in isolation and they do work for negative integers, but its specifically when putting them together that causes this.

Comment: You put the `-` in the buffer, but you then "forget" you did that. Your logic is hard to follow, but I would do the `mov ebx, buffer` before you check for negative and then `inc ebx` if you put a `-` sign. By the way, `EscreverInteiro` does not work standalone either. Also, linux newline is just `0ah`. Oh and learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Well, with that change I get the `-` last, so `12-` ... so close! LOL

Comment: Since you are printing the characters in reverse one by one in a loop you need to put the `-` last. Your code would really be a lot simpler if you put the digits backwards into the buffer, and then you could even use a single write.